# 2 query in redis instead 1

Tags: python, numpy, redis

I want to find N nearest neighbours in redis with ANN.
A saved my data with following shcema and created index via python api:

```py
SCHEMA = [
    TextField("uuid"),
    VectorField("embedding", "HNSW", {"TYPE": "FLOAT32", "DIM": 120, "DISTANCE_METRIC": "L2"}),
    NumericField("timestamp"),
]

conn.ft("vectors").create_index(fields=SCHEMA, definition=IndexDefinition(prefix=["vector:"], index_type=IndexType.HASH))
```

For example, I want to find N neighbours for uuid = "123". I can do it with 2 sequential queries. First, get vector from redis. Second, get N neighbours from redis.

Can I get neighbours with one query?

Also I have a problem with getting vector from ANN. I save vectors by converting numpy array to bytes. But when I get vector from Redis, I can't decode it. This problem probably will disappear, if I could find a neighbours with one query.

```py
np.frombuffer(conn.ft("vector").search(Query('@uuid:123').return_fields("vector").dialect(2)).docs[0].embedding.encode()) failed. 

ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size`
```

I use following query for KNN search

```
query = Query(base_query).return_fields("uuid", "timestamp", "vector_score").sort_by("vector_score").dialect(2)
results = conn.ft("vectors").search(query, query_params={"vector": vec})
```